# Output Capacitor value calculation based on Transient response in Buck converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, transient, bypass-capacitor

In Buck design,

The output capacitor's initial value is calculated based on how much current transient buck will support.
Few equations took from appnotes.
[image]

from these equations,
for A given Vin(12V),Vout(0.925),Istep(12A @ 20A/us) and Cout(884uF) combination,
Vovershoot is large compared to Vundershoot.

from my understanding, **Undershoot is occurred** **during Load increase** which is 
worse than **Overshoot which is occurred during Load Unloading** .

But as per equations Overshoot value is large compared to Overshoot value.

Is there any theoretical area behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that with the given values, Vin >> Vout.

A qualitative way of looking at this is:
When the voltage across the inductor is large (this voltage is Vin-Vout for Vunder), it takes a short time for the inductor to make up the current step. Relatively, a smaller amount of deficit energy is drained from Cout.
When the voltage across the inductor is small (this voltage is Vout for Vover), it takes a long time to make up the current step. Therefore, a greater amount of excess energy is dumped into Cout.

------ New response to comment below

[image]

The line sketched in red would be more to scale in time for Vin >> Vout. Notice the sizes of the hatched areas which represent the current deficit and the current excess which have to be made up by the capacitor. All this is consistent with the energy change of the inductor being the same.

----- New response
There are two common applications for the buck converter. One is to control the current, as in a LED driver. The other is to control the voltage, which is what you are looking at here. From the given equations, they seem to imply that the control loop makes instantaneous control decisions.

In contrast, a typical buck voltage regulator senses the output voltage, feeds that into a control loop of limited bandwidth. Limited bandwidth means control delay. With the control delay being larger than the inductor charging or discharging time, the transient load response is then dominated by the control delay. So we do see treatments of transient load response based on the control bandwidth in datasheets.

I have not worked on any power supplies for recent generation Intel processors. That is one place where this description maybe more relevant. So perhaps look there.

Comment: But Change in energy is same 0.5*L*i_initial^2 - 0.5*L*i_final^2 . only either Load increasing or reducing...

Comment: I understood now....let me think more about it....I am seeing Transient response curves in most of the buck datasheets but i can't able to find the difference in Overshoot and undershoot shown in datasheets....do you have any document with actual curves measured Iout and Vout under transients...